# I have a text-box and I want to enter a string in language A

Tags: c++, c, google-translate

I have a text-box, and I want to enter a string in language A and send it to [Google Translate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Translate). After Google has translated it, I want to take the new string (in language B) (after translation) and store it in some variable.

How can I do it?

Comment: Reposting a question that was previously closed is frowned upon here.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth - At least this time they have posted enough information to make their requirements clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea is shown in a simple example of Language Translation like this:

```
google.language.translate("Hello world", "en", "es", function(result) {
  if(!result.error) {
    var container = document.getElementById("translation");
    container.innerHTML = result.translation;
  }
});
```

`translation` is the id of your textbox. In this case where you put the translation result.

`result` is the translation itself. You can assign it to a new variable in any way you want.

In the above example you're translating "Hello world" from "en" (English) to "es" (Spanish).

The above code is written in JavaScript.

Take a look at [Google AJAX Language API](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlanguage/documentation/) for more detailed steps.

Comment: @nisnis84: This is Javascript. To use it from C/C++ you'd need something like libcurl and a JSON parser

Answer (score 2):

Read on [Google AJAX Language API](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlanguage/) to understand how you can use Google's translation services programmatically.