# Automatic text translation

Tags: web-services, machine-learning, nlp, machine-translation

What tools or web services are available for machine text translation.

For example

```
ENGLISH TEXT > SERVER or LIB > GERMAN TEXT
```

Libraries are also acceptable.

Is [Google language API](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlanguage/) the only one ?

Comment: Check if this helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397103/i-have-a-text-box-and-i-want-to-enter-a-string-in-language-a/2397118#2397118 You also have this one: [Add Value to Your Online Application with Babylon API](http://vip.babylon.com/products/api.html) More to the stack: [Microsoft Translator API v2](http://www.microsofttranslator.com/mix2010/) [An API for Exchanging Texts for Translation](http://www.translated.net/en/translation-api)

Comment: Yeah Google language API is good but i cant be the only one + i don't think  u can use this in a desktop or mobile app without internet

Comment: If you want to translate without internet access that would be a really big app since the translation memories, glossaries are really big files that should go with your app.

Comment: There are a plenty of different Machine Translation APIs: Google, Microsoft, Yandex, IBM, PROMT, Systran, Baidu, YeeCloud, DeepL, SDL, SAP. I may refer you to our recent evaluation study (November 2017): https://www.slideshare.net/KonstantinSavenkov/state-of-the-machine-translation-by-intento-november-2017-81574321

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, just going with [Google's translation API](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlanguage/) is probably the best and easiest thing to do.

Google's API is easy to use and, depending on the language pairs being translated, their translation system is either as good or much better than everything else.

**Open Source Translation Packages**

However, there are also some really good open source tools for machine translation. State-of-the-art packages include:

- [cdec (C++)](http://cdec-decoder.org/index.php?title=Main_Page)
- [Joshua (Java)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/joshua/)
- [Moses (C++)](http://www.statmt.org/moses/)
- [Phrasal (Java) - soon to be released](http://nlp.stanford.edu/phrasal/)

Unlike translation APIs, you can use these tools without needing access to the Internet. More importantly, you can use these tools without running into any throttling or limits that the free APIs impose if you are trying to translate larger amounts of data.

**Training Data**

To use the open source machine translation packages, you'll need training data. If you're translating between English to German, or between some other European languages, you can use Phillip Koehn's [Europarl parallel corpus](http://www.statmt.org/europarl/).

If you're interested in a European Union (EU) language that's not in the Europarl parallel corpus, you can gather the data by crawling the [proceedings of the European parliament](http://www.europarl.europa.eu/omk/omnsapir.so/calendar?APP=CRE&LANGUE=EN). All the EU proceedings are translated into each of the EU languages and made available for free online, which makes them a very good source of machine translation training data.

Comment: As of today you can also use the DeepL Pro API. It povides [better results](https://www.deepl.com/quality.html) than Google.